# ¿Cómo solucionar los siguientes errores en Visual Studio al instalar SDL2?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++

He seguido de forma precisa varios tutoriales acerca de la instalación de SDL2 para iniciar con el desarrollo de mi primer videojuego en 2D. Cuando intento ejecutar mi programa me dice que el archivo .exe no puede ser encontrado. Si presiono "build" me da los siguientes errores:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Parece que tienes un conflicto de versiones.  Que sistema operativo tienes y que version de SDL2 instalaste?

Comment: Windows 10, SDL2 2.0.8